# iptables redirect 80 to 8080 but block public 8080 access

Tags: http, redirect, port, iptables

I have some `iptables` rules which redirect requests for port 80 onto our application server (GlassFish) at port 8080 (and also SSL ports too but I've left them out for simplicity).

Whilst what we have works fine (and I don't personally have an issue with it) port 8080 is also open to the outside world if someone wished to specify it in the url. It has been mandated that port 8080 should be closed off from access from the outside world and only 80 be open.

I don't wish to change the listener on the application server (as to use port 80 this appears to need elevated permissions for the user running the app server) and the listener on port 8080 needs to know the source IP of the packet as the application audits the requests to the application (i.e. we can't change the source IP address to a local one).

The current `iptables` config is below. Does anyone know if there is a way to block 8080 from the public internet whilst retaining the source IP in the packets redirected to from port 80?

Many thanks in advance.

```
    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP

    # allow establishment of connections initialised by my outgoing packets
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    # accept anything on localhost
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

    ################################################################
    #individual ports tcp 
    ################################################################
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

    #drop everything else
    iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

    ################################################################
    #Redirection Rules
    ################################################################
    # redirection rules (allowing forwarding from localhost)
    iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

    # redirection http
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Comment: did you consider blocking port 8080 and relaying on httpd proxypass?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There's no apache or mod_proxy available on this server at present (which I understand it would need..?), but obviously if it's not possible with iptables - or standard Linux packages - then I guess it's something to look into.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way I've found to accomplish this is to use the MARK target in the mangle table's PREROUTING chain.

Add a rule to tag the packets you want to block:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Then, before you allow port 8080 add this to DROP marked packets:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

Comment: Perfect - I was wondering if it was possible with iptables alone, but this worked well. Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't allowed when I tried - it told me I didn't have enough reputation! ...Something I hear all too often.

Comment: In my particular case, while the DROP did indeed prohibit access to port 8080, an outside `nmap` scan revealed that there is a *filtered* port 8080. The solution for me was to instead of `iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP` use `iptables -A INPUT -p TCP -m mark --mark 1 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`.

Answer (score 4):

I handled this in a slightly different way. I forwarded 443 to 3000 (as above) but also forwarded 3000 to 443. I then allow traffic on 3000 but block it on 443. When filtering the 443 traffic should only be originally from port 3000.

I'm using ufw so the filter rules were entered using that tool. I added the nat rules in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 443
```

Comment: That is really clever.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for this, but I come up with another solution which might be more straightforward for most people.

Just redirect port 8080 to another closed port (3000 for example):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Then you may access the app at port 8080 for your local machine and others on the Internet may only see port 80 opened.